# How to find where the app is crashing?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Below is the logs:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c

0   libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 5
respondsToSelector:
1
CoreLocation    
(null) + 23946
2
CoreLocation    
(null) + 5230
3
CoreLocation    
(null) + 972
4
CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
5
CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 216
6
CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun + 1714
7
CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
8
CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
9
GraphicsServices    
GSEventRunModal + 136
10  UIKit   
UIApplicationMain + 1440
11
Wines   
main.m line 40
main
```

Comment: There generally is a green arrow at the left of the text editor (the grey area). The first thing that comes to mind about this error is to check if any object around the breakpoint is NULL/NIL

Comment: This is not happening every time. I have so many variables and objects and it is hard to find which one is set to NULL/NIL. I understand object is trying to read memory and which is retuning NULL how can I find it ? I enable NSZombie and try to see what is happening ? But As I said it is not happening every time.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac you can find backtrace of your crashes in *Console* app under *User Diagnostic Reports*.

There you can find the crash file. Since your crash probably happens in your custom code, you probably sending some fishy values.

You cannot tell where the crash is happening, since your backtrace is stripped out. So either try to compile your code with the debug symbols, or use dtrace/dtruss to debug your app.

The `objc_msgSend` is a standard function of Objective-C.

Read also:

- [objc_msgSend](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/objc_msgsend.html) at ridiculousfish
- [gcc/objc/objc-act.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-4061/gcc/objc/objc-act.c) at opensource apple